# How to make submit button work and showing the results in another page with only using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign-up form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <form class="center" action="submit.htm" method="post">
            <h2>Enter information here</h2>
            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="category" for="firstname">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="category" for="lastname">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="category" for="meal">With Meal?</label>

                <input type="radio" name="meal" value="no" id="no" checked>
                <label class="value" for="no">NO</label>

                <input type="radio" name="meal" value="yes" id="yes">
                <label class="value" for="yes">YES</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="category" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <label class="category" for="number">Contact number</label>
                <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the output of whatever the user input in a different page after clicking submit. how can i do this without using php and only javascript? JS is very hard for me to nderstand so pls help :(

Comment: I see you are using some pretty strict indentation :) anyway, you can do it with javascript only, just check keywords such as `event handling submit`, `event prevent default` and `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

If you use POST method you have to use any server side language like PHP. If you want to achieve the same thing in JavaScript it is very easy. Change the method to get.

```
<form class="center" action="submit.htm" method="get">
```

You can write your submit.htm like this.

```
<div id='firstname'></div>
<div id='lastname'></div>
<div id='meal'></div>
<div id='email'></div>
<div id='number'></div>
```

Your JavaScript code goes here.

```
var data = getJsonFromUrl();
document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = data['firstname'];
document.getElementById("lastname").innerHTML = data['lastname'];
document.getElementById("meal").innerHTML = data['meal'];
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = data['email'];
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = data['number'];

function getJsonFromUrl() {
  var query = location.search.substr(1);
  var result = {};
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: i tried it. its saying {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}

Comment: change the method to GET in your form html. It works for me.

Comment: i got it! thank you but, one last question : in submit.htm , how do i put like Name: [result] , Last Name: [result]

Comment: You have to write it in different divs like 
<div>Name:</div<div id='firstname'></div